# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'WaterWomen' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

it's just one of the school work i'm doing and even teacher can not slove it.
everytime i click the sell button and restock button for waterwomen it makes this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/idlelib/run.py", line 121, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/queue.py", line 175, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/jiho/Documents/DTS3/version3.py", line 87, in <lambda>
    mbutton = Button(mGui,text ='SELL 1',command = lambda: WaterWomenSell()).place (x=20, y=140)
  File "/Users/jiho/Documents/DTS3/version3.py", line 50, in WaterWomenSell
    Watertext = WaterWomen.get()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'WaterWomen' referenced before assignment
```

Code

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
mGui = Tk()

from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

def mReset():
if "SuperDude":
    SuperDude = 8
elif "LizardMan":
    comicstock = 12
else:
    comicstock = 3
    return


def mQuit():

mExit = messagebox.askyesno(title="Quit",message="Are you sure?")
if mExit >0:
   mGui.destroy()
   return

def mOpen():

myopen = filedialog.askopenfile()
return

def SuperDudeSell():
Supertext = SuperDude.get()
SuperDude.set(SuperDude.get() - 1)
Superlabel = Label(mGui,text=Supertext).pack
return
def SuperDudeRe():
Supertext = SuperDude.get()
SuperDude.set(SuperDude.get() + 10)
Superlabel = Label(mGui,text=Supertext).pack
return

def LizardManSell():
Lizardtext = LizardMan.get()
LizardMan.set(LizardMan.get() - 1)
Lizardlabel = Label(mGui,text=Lizardtext).pack
return
def LizardManRe():
Lizardtext = LizardMan.get()
LizardMan.set(LizardMan.get() + 10)
Lizardlabel = Label(mGui,text=Lizardtext).pack
return

def WaterWomenSell():
Watertext = WaterWomen.get()
WaterWomen.set(WaterWomen.get() - 1)
WaterWomen = Label(mGui,text=Watertext).pack
return
def WaterWomenRe():
Watertext = WaterWomen.get()
WaterWomen.set(WaterWomen.get() + 10)
WaterWomen = Label(mGui,text=Watertext).pack
return



SuperDude = IntVar()
SuperDude.set('8')
LizardMan = IntVar()
LizardMan.set('12')
WaterWomen = IntVar()
WaterWomen.set('3')

SuperDudeL = Label(textvariable = (SuperDude)).place (x=170, y=20)
LizardManL = Label(textvariable = (LizardMan)).place (x=170, y=70)
WaterWomenL = Label(textvariable = (WaterWomen)).place (x=170, y =120)

mGui.geometry('230x200+500+300')
mGui.title('COMIC BOOK STORE')
mlable = Label(mGui,text='Comic Book Store',fg='purple').place (x=70, y=0)
mlable = Label(mGui,text='<Super Dude> Left stock:').place (x=10, y=20)
mlable = Label(mGui,text='<Lizard Man> Left stock:').place (x=10, y=70)
mlable = Label(mGui,text='<Water Women> Left stock:').place (x=10, y=120)

#Super Dude
mbutton = Button(mGui,text ='SELL 1',command = lambda: SuperDudeSell()).place (x=20, y=40)
mbutton = Button(mGui,text ='RESTOCK 10',command = lambda: SuperDudeRe()).place (x=100, y=40)
#Lizard Man
mbutton = Button(mGui,text ='SELL 1',command = lambda: LizardManSell()).place (x=20, y=90)
mbutton = Button(mGui,text ='RESTOCK 10',command = lambda: LizardManRe()).place (x=100, y=90)
#Water Women
mbutton = Button(mGui,text ='SELL 1',command = lambda: WaterWomenSell()).place (x=20, y=140)
mbutton = Button(mGui,text ='RESTOCK 10',command = lambda: WaterWomenRe()).place (x=100, y=140)



# Menu Construction

Menubar=Menu(mGui)


filemenu = Menu(Menubar, tearoff = 1)
filemenu.add_command(label="Reset",command = mReset)
filemenu.add_command(label="close",command = mQuit)

Menubar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=filemenu)
mGui.config(menu=Menubar)


# SetUp

setupmenu = Menu(Menubar,tearoff = 0)
setupmenu.add_checkbutton(label = "Auto")

Menubar.add_cascade(label="SetUp",menu=setupmenu)



# Help Menu

helpmenu = Menu(Menubar,tearoff = 0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Docs")
Menubar.add_cascade(label="Help",menu=helpmenu)
```

Comment: Can you narrow down the example to a minimal set that still has the same symptom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WaterWomen functions you appear to have mistyped the names for the label vars.

Compare

```
def WaterWomenRe():
    Watertext = WaterWomen.get()
    WaterWomen.set(WaterWomen.get() + 10)
    WaterWomen = Label(mGui,text=Watertext).pack
    # should have been Waterlabel
    return
```

with

```
def LizardManRe():
    Lizardtext = LizardMan.get()
    LizardMan.set(LizardMan.get() + 10)
    Lizardlabel = Label(mGui,text=Lizardtext).pack
    return
```

The error message you are getting is because of your misnamed variable, python thinks you are trying access `WaterWomen` before it exists. That is, `WaterWomen = Label(mGui,text=Watertext).pack` comes after `Watertext = WaterWomen.get()`. Even though WaterWomen exists at the global scope, because you assign to it, Python will treat it like its a local variable which doesn't exist until it is first assigned to. If you actually wanted to access a global variable and then modify it then you need to declare the variable as being global at the top of the function. eg.

```
def add_to_var(x):
    global var
    new_var = var + x # access
    var = new_var # assignment
```